# Align data frame with missing values to full data frame based on order

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyverse

I have two data frames in R. One "reference" frame that contains all my observations, and another additional data frame that contains extra data for a (large) subset of the observations. I would like to join the two frames together, filling in the missing values with `NA`. The complication (that makes me unable to just use `merge`/`left_join`) is that observations are only uniquely identified using a combination of several columns, but the additional data frame **only contains one** of the identifying columns. However, **the order of the two data frames is guaranteed to be the same.**

Here is some minimal example data, that also illustrates the problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fruit_sizes = tribble(~fruit,       ~colour,  ~size,
                      "apple",      "red",    5,
                      "cherry",     "red",    2,
                      "strawberry", "red",    3,
                      "apple",      "green",  6,
                      "lime",       "green",  4,
                      "apple",      "yellow", 5)

fruit_prices = tribble(~fruit,       ~price,
                       "apple",      1.5,
                       "strawberry", 0.2,
                       "lime",       2.0,
                       "apple",      1.3)

# Desired result:
#
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   fruit      colour  size price
#   <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 apple      red        5   1.5
# 2 cherry     red        2  NA
# 3 strawberry red        3   0.2  
# 4 apple      green      6  NA  
# 5 lime       green      4   2  
# 6 apple      yellow     5   1.3
```

(Fruits are identified by name and colour, but the `prices` table lacks colour information. However, both tables have the fruits in the same order.)

So now my question is how to use the order information of the second table to align/match its data to the first table. It can be assumed that no ambiguous cases exist. (I am using tibbles in the example and in my actual data, but a non-`tidyverse` solution would also be fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop solution -

```
fruit_sizes$price <- NA
j <- 1
for(i in seq(nrow(fruit_sizes))) {
    if(fruit_sizes$fruit[i] == fruit_prices$fruit[j]) {
      fruit_sizes$price[i]  <- fruit_prices$price[j]
      j <- j + 1
    }
}
fruit_sizes

#  fruit      colour  size price
#  <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 apple      red        5   1.5
#2 cherry     red        2  NA  
#3 strawberry red        3   0.2
#4 apple      green      6  NA  
#5 lime       green      4   2  
#6 apple      yellow     5   1.3
```

Comment: This looks like it can work with the example data fine.